# Selector give me a runtime error on Shapelets

Tags: python, dataframe, function, selector

I'm using Shapelets, to create a presentation for my team on a project I have been working on for a couple of weeks on.
I am working on displaying the characteristics of a population's global population and their population by postal code. So in that case I have created a selector which should update the image directly

```
def plot_language_bar(papa_person_group: DataFrame, selector: int)-> Image:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 7))
    language[language.index == selector].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
    return app.image(img=fig)
```

I then place the selector and my image

```
selector = app.selector(title="Select the Postal Code", options=['33122','33125','33126','33127','33128','33129','33130','33131','33132','33133','33134','33135','33136','33137','33138','33139','33140','33141','33142','33143','33144','33145','33146','33147','33148','33149','33150','33151','33152','33153','33155','33156','33157','33161','33162','33165','33166','33167','33168','33169','33170','33172','33173','33174','33175','33176','33177','33178','33179','33180','33181','33182','33183','33184','33185','33186','33187','33188','33189','33190','33193','33194'])
app.place(selector)

image_partiel_language_bar = app.image()
image_partiel_language_bar.bind(plot_language_bar, papa_person_group, selector)

vf_income.place(image_partiel_income_bar)
```

However, when I tried to register the data app and use the selector, I had a Runtime error and the selector didn´t work.
Any help would be appreciated, as I'm new to data analysis and would like guidance on using Shapelets effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I saw where your error is. The problem is happening to you right now at the `selector: int`. The selector must be first passed as `str` and then changed to an `int`.

```
def plot_language_bar(papa_person_group: DataFrame, selector: str)-> Image:
selector = int(selector)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 7))
language[language.index == selector].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
return app.image(img=fig)
```

With this, you will be able to get your embedded function working.

We are currently working to change this and in the future, you will be able to get the selector as an `int`.

you can look at your documentation https://shapelets.io/doc/ https://github.com/shapelets/shapelets-demo